# Download files from Google Books

Tags: c#, console-application

I'm writing very simple application. It is supposed to download files from internet. I have URLs and names for files to save in tables. But my code doesn't work.

```
for (int i = 1; i < links.Length; i++)
{
    Uri uri = new Uri(links[i]);

    HttpWebRequest webRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(uri);
    webRequest.Method = "GET";

    HttpWebResponse webResponse = (HttpWebResponse)webRequest.GetResponse();

    Stream responseStream = webResponse.GetResponseStream();
    StreamReader responseStreamReader = new StreamReader(responseStream);
    String result = responseStreamReader.ReadToEnd();

    StreamWriter w = new StreamWriter(savepath + names[i]);
    w.Write(result);
    w.Close();

    break;
}
```

example url:
`http://books.google.pl/books?id=yOz1ePt39WQC&pg=PA2&img=1&zoom=3&hl=pl&sig=ACfU3U0MDQtXGU_3YVqGvcsDiWLLcKh0KA&w=800&gbd=1`

example name: 
    `002.png`

Files are to be saved as PNG image but instead I get something that begins with
    `<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN""http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">`

Second qestion. How can I detect HTTP 404 error when trying to download?

EDIT:
My bad. my links were incorrect. After replacing `&amp;` with `&` they are correct.
Example link (correctted):

`http://books.google.pl/books?id=yOz1ePt39WQC&pg=PA2&img=1&zoom=3&hl=pl&sig=ACfU3U0MDQtXGU_3YVqGvcsDiWLLcKh0KA&w=800&gbd=1`

Despite of that I can't still download PNGs correctly.
They are not opening. But at least they are not HTML pages.
I'm thinking that trying to save them as a string is not good idea. But I don't know how else I could do that. Maybe using byte[] or something?

Comment: If you go to that URL manually, it takes you to a HTML page ...

Comment: I realized that my links were incorrect. I made an edit.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Have you tried [WebClient.DownloadFile](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms144194.aspx) ?

```
string url = "http://books.google.pl/books?id=yOz1ePt39WQC&pg=PA2&img=1&zoom=3&hl=pl&sig=ACfU3U0MDQtXGU_3YVqGvcsDiWLLcKh0KA&w=800&gbd=1";
string file = "002.png";

WebClient wc = new WebClient();
wc.DownloadFile(url, file);
```

will save the image in the application directory as 002.png.